# Select a Sum the last 5 rows

Tags: mysql

I'm building a little quiz game in PHP/MySQL. After asking questions I want a screen to display how many of the last round were answered correctly.

Im storing whether they were answered correctly or not in a table that looks like this:

```
rowID | questionid | playerid | answercorrect |
1     | 1          | 1        | 1             |
2     | 2          | 1        | 1             |
3     | 3          | 1        | 1             |
4     | 4          | 1        | 1             |
5     | 5          | 1        | 0             |
6     | 6          | 1        | 1             |
7     | 7          | 1        | 1             |
```

I want to see how many of the last x (usually 5) questions were answered correctly.

I thought this would be simple. I'm trying this:

```
SELECT sum( answercorrect ) FROM `answersgiven` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5
```

I thought this would sum the `answercorrect` column for the last 5 rows, giving me an answer of 4, but it's giving me 7, which is the result for ALL of the rows.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious. It seems like a simple thing to want to do.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT sum(answercorrect) 
FROM (SELECT answercorrect FROM `answersgiven` ORDER BY rowID DESC LIMIT 5) t1
```

[**Example Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c893/4)

In your query, the `LIMIT` clause affects the overall result: So first all are summed up (which results in one row - the sum over all rows) and then the first 5, if available, are taken (which again is just the one row).

The easiest way of achieving your target is to first select just the first 5 rows (in the subselect) and then sum up afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

try this query

```
SELECT sum(col) 
FROM (SELECT col FROM `table` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5) t1
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. Just sum up those top 5 answers now:

```
SELECT SUM('top5')
FROM 
  (SELECT answercorrect AS 'top5' 
   FROM `answersgiven` 
   ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5) 'x'
```

Comment: You forgot the alias: `FROM (SELECT ...) AS x`

Comment: Also, what's the `SUM` inside the subselect for..?

Comment: `SUM('top5')` will give you `0`.